# REPL session for a ClojureScript library in the vein of `lein try`

Tags: node.js, clojure, clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop

Sometimes I want to try out a library in a REPL. For example when I need to know the date 100 days from now, I do:

```
lein try clj-time
(require '[clj-time.core :as t])
(t/plus (t/today) (t/days 100))
```

Or with boot:

```
boot -d clj-time repl -e "(require '[clj-time.core :as t])"
(t/plus (t/today) (t/days 100))
```

This is already great, but this still has a few seconds of start up time.

My question: can I get the same functionality using ClojureScript and Node and perhaps have a faster startup time? How can I get the example above with [cljs-time](https://github.com/andrewmcveigh/cljs-time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Planck with the jar you're wanting to try by adding it to Planck's "classpath" (it's not an actual classpath since there's no JVM involved). See the [Planck Dependencies documentation](http://planck-repl.org/dependencies.html).

E.g.:

```
planck -c ~/.m2/repository/com/andrewmcveigh/cljs-time/0.4.0/cljs-time-0.4.0.jar
```

Comment: For documentation, this does exactly what I want:

`planck -c ~/.m2/repository/com/andrewmcveigh/cljs-time/0.4.0/cljs-time-0.4.0.jar -e "(require '[cljs-time.core :as t])" -r`

Thanks again Martin.

Comment: More information here: https://gist.github.com/borkdude/8d43941031518a0a85f9732c270b119a